# How to use variable granularity at x axis?

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

Start in Jan and use kind of a logarithmic scale till June - then fortnightly intervals.

Ref: http://jsfiddle.net/NtBPk/146/

```
/* Edit Below*/
 axisLabelFormatter: function(d, gran) {             
      return Dygraph.dateAxisFormatter(d , gran);
   },
/*Edit Above*/
```

Is it possible to add some code such that graph from Jan to Sept is relatively closer than latter part of graph.

Or Let me phrase it this way:

The x-axis labels should be " Jan, March, May, July, Sept, Oct,mid-Oct,Nov,mid-Nov,Dec "

Or :

Is it possible to explicitly define which points to display on x-Axis.

Comment: Please phrase this as a question. It's not at all clear what you're asking.

Comment: @danvk Question Edited!

Comment: So you want to scrunch the bit from Jan-Sep and expand the rest? It is possible, but you'll have to give up on using dates in the first column of your data. The independent variable (first column) is always shown on a linear axis in dygraphs, so whatever transformation you want to do has to be baked into it already.

Comment: Can You please provide some code to do so?

Comment: @danvk just tell me the Dygraph option on which i should be focusing. Is it "ticker"?

Comment: ticker, axisLabelFormatter and valueFormatter. You'll need to tweak all of them.